# Spring-XD Error while processing: KafkaMessage, MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spring-xd

I am using Spring-XD to read a topic from kafka, filter the data using spark- streaming-processor and sink the data into the spark.

The command i used to deploy stream is:

```
stream create spark-streaming-word-count --definition "kafka --zkconnect=localhost:2181 --topic=log-stream | java-word-count | log" --deploy
```

And the error i got for this is:

```
2015-05-23 11:36:16,190 1.1.1.RELEASE ERROR dispatcher-1 listener.LoggingErrorHandler - Error while processing: KafkaMessage [Message(magic = 0, attributes = 0, crc = 3699841462, key = java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=6 cap=437], payload = java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=427 cap=427]), KafkaMessageMetadata [offset=26353, nextOffset=26354, Partition[topic='log-stream', id=0]]
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'admin:default,admin,singlenode,hsqldbServer:9393.spark-streaming-word-count.0'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:81)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:239)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:248)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:171)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:119)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
```

Please help me to resolve this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the stream deployment status? The shell command `stream list` would give you the stream deployment status. Also, try `runtime modules` to see what modules are running. It appears like the downstream module `java-word-count` is not deployed yet.